# Section outside multicols environment if section contains a table

Tags: floats, conditionals, multicol

I am using `\begin{multicols*}{2}` to split my text in two columns on the landscape format paper. Now if I have a tabular, it resizes the tabular to `\linewidth`. What I want is to ask if there is a tabular in a section and if it is the case, I want the whole section to be outside the `\begin{multicols*}{2}`. I know that I could do it manually by inserting `\end{multicols*}` before the section and `\begin{multocols*}{2}` after the section, but I need it to be done automatically, if it is even possible. Maybe someone could help me with my question. I would be very greatful for help.

This is what I see:

[image]

And this is what I want it to be:

[image]

Comment: TeX works in a streaming fashion it does not know (unless you tell it) that when it sees the start of a section there is a table in that section. You could define `\section` so it _always_ ends multicol if it is in multicol, but you can not (practically, without some complicated multi-pass test) make that conditional on the content of the section

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please make your comment here an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX works in a streaming fashion it does not know (unless you tell it) that when it sees the start of a section there is a table in that section. You could define `\section` so it always ends `multicol` if it is in `multicol`, but you can not (practically, without some complicated multi-pass test) make that conditional on the content of the section.